# How to compute gravitational wave TT-gauge components from the Riemann tensor?

Tags: waves, gravity, curvature, gravitational-waves

In many text books on general relativity it is shown that you can compute the gravitational wave metric in the TT-gauge by projections with the Lambda tensor.

$$
 \bar{h}^{\mu \nu} = -\frac{4G}{c^4} \int_\mathcal{V} \frac{T^{\mu \nu}(t-\frac{|x-x'|}{c}, x')}{|x-x'|} d^3x' 
$$

$$
 h_{i j}^{TT} =  \Lambda (\hat{n})_{ij,kl} \bar{h}^{k l}
$$

Where we define the lambda tensor as:

$$
\Lambda_{ij,kl}(\hat{n}) = P_{ik}P_{jl}-P_{ij}P_{kl} 
$$
$$
P_{ij} = \delta_{ij}-n_in_j
$$

$n_i$ is the propagation direction of the gravitational wave in respect to the source. In Gravitation by Minser and Thorne it's stated that you can also compute the TT-gauge components through the invariance of the Riemann tensor. The Riemann tensor in linearised gravity is given as:

$$
R_{\mu \nu \sigma \rho} = \frac{1}{2}( \partial_{\nu} \partial_{\sigma}h_{\mu \rho} +   \partial_{\mu} \partial_{\rho}h_{\nu \sigma}-\partial_{\mu}\partial_{\sigma}h_{\nu \rho}-\partial_{\nu}\partial_{\rho}h_{\mu \sigma})
$$

Thus its possible to derive the formula:

$$
h_{ij}^{TT} = \omega^{-2} R_{0i0j}
$$

But when I use this formula for any direction except along the z-axis it yields the incorrect components for $h_{ij}^{TT}$.  Could someone help me compute the metric components of a gravitational wave emitted by a binary system composed of two point masses in the TT-gauge along the x-axis using the Riemann tensor ?